# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError) with ocra

Tags: ruby, ocra

I try to convert a sample ruby script to an executable file with the ocra gem.Here is my ruby script.

```
puts "Hello word"
```

Gives me the following error when running `ocra test.rb`

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:34:in `tr': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:34:in `to_posix'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:57:in `subpath?'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:611:in `block (2 levels) in find_gem_files'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:609:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:609:in `block in find_gem_files'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:597:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:597:in `find_gem_files'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:755:in `build_exe'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:1231:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

My version of ruby

```
ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
```

Is there a good way to convert a ruby script to an executable file ?

Comment: Perhaps there is an apostrophe in the file path to your Ruby script. Try to put all Ruby related files into a file path that does not contain any UTF-8 characters. This is my guess. Just a guess, but looking at the call stack, it could be possible this is where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I tried to put my ruby files into a file path wich not contain UTF-8 characters but unfortunalety the problem still the same.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's too hard to guess what the problem could be. I would try to file a bug report, since it looks like it could be a bug. https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues

Comment: I reported this problem on ocra github but i seem to be abandonaded by the developers, the answers and responses are maked by the users each others.If i solve this issue i will put the correct way to resolve it here.Thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my Window username contained the character è. Like Casper mentioned, UFT-8 must be respected with ocra. I followed this link to solve my problem and then restarted ocra and the issue was fixed.

[Change user name on windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89060-change-name-user-profile-folder-windows-10-a.html)